# Java jackson parse large JSON to XML with specific xml array format

Tags: java, jackson

Help me figure out how to convert Jason node to xml with `Jacson` library.
My JSON is large (from 10 to 200 mb) and contains many objects. So I won’t be able to convert through the class and use `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "someName")`. It because this json has a lotof dynamic elements. And the problem is that the format of arrays in xml should be:

```
<test_data>
     <data_type>numeric</data_type>
     <value>
         <Item>0</Item>
         <Item>1</Item>
     </value>
</test_data>

and jason element looks like this:
{
     "test_data": {
         "data_type": "numeric",
         "value": [
             0,
             1
         ]
     }
}
```

if we take this xml and convert it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String xmlStr = """
          <test_data>
            <data_type>numeric</data_type>
            <value>
              <Item>0</Item>
              <Item>1</Item>
            </value>
          </test_data>
            """;
        
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        JsonNode xml = xmlMapper.readTree(xmlStr);
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
        System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(xml));
    }
```

OUTPUT is :

```
{"data_type":"numeric","value":{"Item":["0","1"]}}
```

visa versa:

```
String jsonStr = """
            {
                "test_data" : {
                          "data_type" : "numeric",
                          "value" : [ 0, 1 ]
                        }
            }
            """;

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
        JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readTree(jsonStr.getBytes());
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        System.out.println(xml);
```

OUTPUT:

```
<ObjectNode>
  <test_data>
    <data_type>numeric</data_type>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>1</value>
  </test_data>
</ObjectNode>
```

Simply say, I have JsonNode and I need xml String with specific array format, any idea?

Try find a way to create JsonSerializer for JsonNode but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it on XmlMapper side, so I just modified a input json. Replaced all arrays with name "value" by object with name "value" and copied array`s items to new array with name "Item". code example looks like:

```
private void changeArrayToObject(JsonNode node) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = objectNode.fields();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
                if (entry.getKey() == "value" && entry.getValue().isArray()) {
                    ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) entry.getValue();
                    ObjectNode newObject = new ObjectNode(new JsonNodeFactory(true));
                    entry.setValue(newObject.set("Item", arrayNode));
                    if(isArrayValueObjOrNot(arrayNode)) {
                        for (JsonNode nextNode : arrayNode) {
                            changeArrayToObject(nextNode);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    changeArrayToObject(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Boolean isArrayValueObjOrNot(ArrayNode arrayNode) {
        JsonNode firstElement = arrayNode.get(0);
        if (firstElement.isObject())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```